# BIRT - pagebreak in a table with crosstab

Tags: birt

I have a report (PDF output, 2.6.2) with a table containing crosstab (see attached files for a classic models example). After all report data there has to be a section for signs of peoples responsible for it. And there is strict demand that this section is preceeded with data (at least 1 row) and all signs must be together on 1 page.

Here is [the image of what i should get](http://s24.postimg.org/c14sggik5/W_R.png).

I have a problem with page break, it is in a crosstab or in a table itself. I've tried to manipulate page break section in crosstab, crosstab rows, table sections - still no luck. I remember I was able to do this for a simple table without crosstab in it, so the problem is probably in crosstab.

I've shared [the report without experiment changes](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B16y82GJs5PJZDZucEpaOXljU3c/edit?usp=sharing). I need it in PDF, version 2.6.2.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Question also at http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/30157-page-break-in-a-table-with-crosstab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crosstab and a table with signs must be in same table, then crosstab will have pagebreak. For a table with signs I've added visibility rule to show it on last page only.

There is same problem with nested tables, not only crosstabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have shared the result of your report here [View This](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxJpTXA3mhvSMVdPQXBFaXRIWFU/edit) I think you are expecting your report like this..

Comment: Hi, I've requested access to file by your link, please share it.